# SQL - Sorting this string with numbers

Tags: sql-server

I have the following values and I want to sort this
These are the following values:

```
12:23PM IN | 12:26PM OUT
2:10PM IN
11:05AM IN
10:58AM IN | 11:00AM OUT
1:02PM IN | 1:05PM OUT
2:12PM IN | 2:25PM OUT
Collection Remarks: counter
11:47AM IN | 11:49AM OUT
12:42PM IN
12:58PM IN
12:55PM IN
12:54PM IN
12:49PM IN | 2:45PM OUT
```

I need to sort it like this

```
10:58AM IN | 11:00AM OUT
11:05AM IN
11:47AM IN | 11:49AM OUT
12:23PM IN | 12:26PM OUT
12:42PM IN
12:49PM IN | 2:45PM OUT
12:54PM IN
12:55PM IN
12:58PM IN
1:02PM IN | 1:05PM OUT
2:12PM IN | 2:25PM OUT
Collection Remarks: counter
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Are those values really strings?  Why?

Comment: The problem is that you store multiple values as one string in the first place, violating the most basic table design rule. Don't do it. Those are *two* different types of data. Use two separate fields, eg `time_in` and `time_out` of type `time`.

Answer (score 0):

Parse a portion of your strings to time and order by the result.

```
;WITH ParsedValues AS
(
    SELECT
        T.*,
        ParsedTime = TRY_PARSE(SUBSTRING(T.YourColumn, 1, 7) AS TIME)
    FROM
        YourTable AS T
)
SELECT
    T.*
FROM
    ParsedValues AS T
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN T.ParsedTime IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 999 END,
    T.ParsedTime ASC
```

Although I strongly suggest you correctly store these values as 2 different columns with `time` data type.

Answer (score 0):

I used a custom [sql split string function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx) to split two times (In and Out) from each other using "|" as seperator

```
/*
create table TimeEntries (
    InOut varchar(100)
)
insert into TimeEntries values 
('10:58AM IN | 11:00AM OUT'),
('11:05AM IN'),
('11:47AM IN | 11:49AM OUT'),
('12:23PM IN | 12:26PM OUT'),
('12:42PM IN'),
('12:49PM IN | 2:45PM OUT'),
('12:54PM IN'),
('12:55PM IN'),
('12:58PM IN'),
('1:02PM IN | 1:05PM OUT'),
('2:12PM IN | 2:25PM OUT')
*/
;with cte as (
    select
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by InOut) as rn,
        InOut
    from TimeEntries
)
select
    max(InTime) InTime,
    max(OutTime) OutTime
from (
    select
        rn,
        case when id = 1 then convert(time, ltrim(rtrim(replace(val, 'IN', ''))) ) end as InTime,
        case when id = 2 then convert(time, ltrim(rtrim(replace(val, 'OUT', ''))) ) end as OutTime
    from cte
    cross apply dbo.split(InOut, '|')
) t
group by rn
order by InTime, OutTime
```